# Problem with decimalLongitude and decimalLatitude for create a SpatiaPointDataframe

Tags: r, coordinates, raster, r-raster

I'm new in R and I'm trying to learn.

I have a giant dataframe from Gbif (900.000 rows) with name of my species and decimalLongitude and decimalLatitude but when I tried to create a SpatialPointDataframe as always with `coordinates(data.frame) <-  ~ lon + lat` function  (I changed before the name of columns from decimalLongitude in lon ecc... and I deleted the name of species, so I have only a "lon, lat and species=1" as always in my analysis):

Here is the `head()` function from my dataframe

```
lon            lat      species
1  4.841.452   5317168       1
2 10.380.893  48888992       1
3 12.999.839  52388378       1
4  1.002.614  53190685       1
5  8.820.133  50520302       1
```

and R replied: #Error in .local(obj, ...): cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix

So I see the dataframe and I noticed that my coordinates are a little bit strange.

Do you have some ideas? I need to convert the coordinates?
I looked but I didn't find a solution.
Thank you for spend your time for answer me.

I hope you have a good day and good work!

Comment: Please provide us some example data e.g. the text output of `dput(head(data.frame))`

Comment: i edited the question with your suggestion and the result is : structure(list(lon = c("4.841.452", "10.380.893", "12.999.839",  "1.002.614", "8.820.133", "8.483.664"), lat = c(5317168L, 48888992L,  52388378L, 53190685L, 50520302L, 48896587L), species = c(1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that the `lon` column is of class `character` and not of class `numeric`. So you need to convert this column. Please find one possible solution (cf. reprex below).

**Reprex**

- Your data

```r
points <- read.table(text = "lon            lat      species
1  4.841.452   5317168       1
2 10.380.893  48888992       1
3 12.999.839  52388378       1
4  1.002.614  53190685       1
5  8.820.133  50520302       1", header = TRUE)
```

- Code

```r
library(raster)

# Convert 'lon' column into numeric
points$lon <- as.numeric(gsub("\\." ,"", points$lon))

# converting to SpatialPointsDataFrame
coordinates(points) <- ~lon+lat
```

- Output

```r
points
#> class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
#> features    : 5 
#> extent      : 1002614, 12999839, 5317168, 53190685  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs         : NA 
#> variables   : 1
#> names       : species 
#> min values  :       1 
#> max values  :       1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi @Ludovico. Welcome to SO. Please find above one possible answer. If it meets your needs, please consider marking this answer as "accepted". If not, please tell me what is wrong. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you every so much, finally i understand! i hope you have a good day!

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback @Ludovico. I wish you the best in your work. Cheers.